# IOS Voice Over ignoring focusable elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, anchor, wai-aria

I have an web page with links for products, and the accessibility tree on chrome says that they are focusable, but IOS Voice Over just ignore them. I can swipe on then with Android Talkback but in IOS I can't.

Does Voice Over have this issues? Or can be a problem with my web page?

`<a aria-label="Carregador Veicular Smartphone Tablet MP..." class="box-card-link d-block txt-body-sm color-ui-2 txt-font-body txt-left" href="/products/328e041d49ff4ef89d48">Carregador Veicular Smartphone Tablet MP...</a>`

This is the element that IOS Voice Over is ignoring, there's nothing wrong with it.

The web page is made with React.JS and the anchor is a Link tag from 'react-router-dom'.

I have some functions that hide this elements with aria-hidden but it's show them as well at certain clicks, maybe IOS doesn't know that the DOM alters?

This happens with alerts too, when the page is loaded and one alert is show the IOS Voice Over ignores them as well, even with .focus() on the alert.